# Can't show view in Swift UI with layers of views and onAppear

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

There is a strange case where if you show a view through another view the contents (list of 3 items) of the second view won't show when values are set using onAppear. I'm guessing SwiftUI gets confused since the second views onAppear is called prior to the first views onAppear, but I still think this is weird since both of the views data are only used in their own views. Also, there is no problem if I don't use view models and instead have the data being set using state directly in the view, but then there is yet another problem that the view model declaration must be commented out otherwise I get "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x400000008)". Furthermore, if I check for nil in the first view on the data that is set there before showing the second one, then the second view will be shown the first time you navigate (to the first containing the second), but no other times. I also tried removing content view and starting directly at FirstView and then the screen is just black. I want to understand why these problems happen, setting data through init works but then the init will be called before it's navigated to since that's how NavigationView works, which in turn I guess I could work around by using a deferred view, but there are cases where I would like to do stuff in the background with .task as well and it has the same problem as .onAppear. In any case I would like to avoid work arounds and understand the problem. See comments for better explanation:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // If I directly go to SecondView instead the list shows
            NavigationLink(destination: FirstView()) {
                Text("Go to first view")
            }
        }
    }
}

class FirstViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var listOfItems: [Int]?
    
    func updateList() {
        listOfItems = []
    }
}
struct FirstView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = FirstViewViewModel()
    
    // If I have the state in the view instead of the view model there is no problem.
    // Also need to comment out the view model when using the state otherwise I get Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS runtime exception
    //@State private var listOfItems: [Int]?
    
    var body: some View {
        // Showing SecondView without check for nil and it will never show
        SecondView()
        
        // If I check for nil then the second view will show the first time its navigated to, but no other times.
        /*Group {
            if viewModel.listOfItems != nil {
                SecondView()
            } else {
                Text("Loading").hidden() // Needed in order for onAppear to trigger, EmptyView don't work
            }
        }*/
        
        // If I comment out onAppear there is no problem
       .onAppear {
           print("onAppear called for first view after onAppear in second view")
           viewModel.updateList()
           // listOfItems = []
        }
    }
}
   


class SecondViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var listOfItems = [String]()
    
    func updateList() {
        listOfItems = ["first", "second", "third"]
    }
}
struct SecondView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SecondViewViewModel()
    
    // If I set the items through init instead of onAppear the list shows every time
    init() {
        // viewModel.updateList()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.listOfItems, id: \.self) { itemValue in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                        Text(itemValue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Second View")
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.updateList()
            // The items are printed even though the view don't show
            print("items: \(viewModel.listOfItems)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, it's not recommended to alter the view model's state from within a view - neither in `onAppear` or in any other action. Instead, send "actions" or "events" to the view model (for example, in `onAppear` you might call`viewModel.send(event: .requireData)`). The view model then evaluates a new view state, which is the `@Published` property the view observes.

Comment: Do you mean viewModel.listOfItems = [] in FirstView? It is the same problem if I have a function on the view model that it is called that does the same thing (like I have in SecondView). I updated it so it's the same now.

Comment: Yes, but there are other issues, too. You might first use `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject` as @malhal already pointed out. `@State` and `@StateObject` are meant to be private and "internal" to the view, ie. no external thing, even another view (non-descendants), can read or alter it. In a pure MVVM setup, you do rarely have `@State`, because the View's State will be generated by the View Model, and the View cannot modify it, so they are "let" values. You may pass state values via "bindings" to descendant views, though. But descendants are really just _the_ view anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI. For data transient to a View we use `@State` and `@Binding` to make the View data struct behave like an object.

And FYI initing an object using `@ObservedObject` is an error causing a memory leak, it will be discarded every time the `View` struct is init. When we are creating a Combine loader/fetcher object that we want to have a lifetime tied to the view we init the object using `@StateObject`.

Also you must not do `id: \.self` with `ForEach` for an array of value types cause it'll crash when the data changes. You have to make a struct for your data that conforms to `Identifiable` to be used with `ForEach`. Or if you really do want a static `ForEach` you can do `ForEach(0..<5) {`

Comment: "We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI". Not sure what you mean by this? Classes that implements ObservableObject used by the views are known as view models and using these is very common. I guess I did not completely understand StateObject so I will try it. Regarding the last paragraph I did not know that about ForEach, I though using \.whatever was just a replacement for identifiable where you specify the identifier. In the real app the data is actually from another framework in Kotlin (using Kmm cross platform) so there I use \.id which is unique to that object.

Comment: Works with StateObject. I also verified that when I used ObservedObject in the second view then init for that view model was called twice (1 before onAppear on the first view and also after). Thanks.

Comment: ObervableObject is part of the Combine framework and is used to assign the output of a Combine pipeline to @Published. Using it as a MVVM view model object is a mistake and it’s usually made by someone who hasn’t learned SwiftUI value semantics and is trying to apply their UIKit object-oriented knowledge instead.

Comment: I don't think that's true at all. This architecture is what's thought in the Stanford iOS course and it's also basic MVVM. It's not good to have all your functions and properties defined in the view, much better to use a class for this, and that kind of intermediary is known as a view model. Thanks for helping with StateObject but I don't think you understand MVVM. ObservableObject is very much supposed to be used along with SwiftUI.

Comment: The Stanford course is terrible, that prof doesn't understand SwiftUI at all. Better to use Apple's WWDC videos, you won't see a view model object mentioned. MVVM was created by those who tried to solve the massive view controller problem instead of learning child view controllers and breaking the responder chain in the process.

Comment: @malhal You need a non-View component or a SwiftUI View with a special role, to handle state which cannot or should not be handled in the View. Just think of `onAppear` where folks usually request data, but, you rarely need data always when `onAppear` will be called, and it was painfully as there was a bug where it was called twice in succession. So, better is, you send an "Intent" to some "Handler" (called View Model in MVVM, or simply "Component" in other Frameworks), which handles various states and performs validation, error transformation etc. You won't do this in a view directly.